# getChars function in Scala

Tags: java, scala

I want to run method getChars in scala :

```
scala> val test = "scala is also functional programming"
scala> val testArray : Array[Char] = Array()

scala> test.getChars(1,10, testArray, 0)
```

After running this I am getting below error:

[image: Error Message]

Could someone please help me.

Answer (score 2):

`Array` is not resiable. This means, that when you initialize an array without any elements, it can only be empty. Trying to set any element will result in `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

You can populate it with data using `Array.fill` or at least specify size using the constructor.

P.S.1: What would be even simpler in your case is to use some method on `StringOps`:

```
val testArray: Array[Char] = test.drop(1).take(9).toCharArray
```

P.S.2: Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez suggests (and I agree) to use lists (or maybe other collection type) instead. Those have multiple benefits over arrays. He mentions also `slice`, which is equivalent to consequent `drop` and `take`.

Comment: I would use `test.slice(1, 10).toList` - plain **Arrays** are not recommended.